# I am getting the warning for a piece of code, but the c++ book by bjarne stroustrup is saying it should be an error. what is right here?

Tags: c++, c++11

As per book The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition -

> In C and in older C++ code, you could assign a string literal to a
> non-const char*:
>
> ```
> void f()
> {
>     char* p = "Plato"; // error, but accepted in pre-C++11-standard code
>     p[4] = 'e'; // error : assignment to const
> }
> ```
>
> It would obviously be unsafe to accept that assignment. It was (and
> is) a source of subtle errors, so please don’t grumble too much if
> some old code fails to compile for this reason.

It suggest that, above code should give error, but I am getting a warning instead.

```
    21:22:38 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project study ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\study.o" "..\\src\\study.cpp" 
..\src\study.cpp: In function 'void f()':
..\src\study.cpp:10:13: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
```

Comment: Which compiler and what compiler flags are you using?

Comment: a warning and an error are basically the same thing.  A warning just means the compiler will keep moving on compiling.  To stop that, add `-Werror` to your compiler options to turn warnings into errors.

Comment: I am using gcc c++ compiler. flags are - <br>g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\study.o" "..\\src\\study.cpp"

Comment: its a GCC extension to allow it, other compilers reject it

Comment: Formally, the compiler is required to "issue a diagnostic", and that warning is a diagnostic; having done that, the compiler is free to continue to compiler the code, with an implementation-specific meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GCC compiler is somewhat permissive by default and allows some extension such as implicitly converting away the constness of a string.

Most likely this extension was added to keep compatibility with C.

To disable those extensions, simply add the `--pedantic-errors` flag that will make the compiler refuse invalid code.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/95WE7fEjE)